# Frequency response of an ideal LC circuit

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, inductor, frequency-response

Does the frequency response of an ideal LC circuit exist? The frequency response of a system is defined as: $$\int_0^\infty{h(t)e^{-j\omega t}dt}$$ where \$h(t)\$ is the system's impulse response, but an ideal LC circuit is marginally stable, i.e. its impulse response doesn't decay or blow up as time approaches \$\infty\$, so it makes sense that the integral doesn't converge, therefore it shouldn't exist. Am I wrong?
I might be, because the frequency response is used to solve for the output of the circuit. If a sinusoidal input \$a\sin(\omega t+\theta)\$ is provided to the circuit, the forced response is equal to \$|H(j\omega)|a\sin\big(\omega t+\theta+\angle H(j\omega)\big)\$ (from this [lecture](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/ee102/freq.pdf)), where \$H(j\omega)\$ is the frequency response. If I assume that it exists, I get the correct forced response (as if I solved it through undetermined coefficients if I instead formed a differential equation). So does/doesn't it exist?

Answer (score 1):

> Does the frequency response of an ideal LC circuit exist?

Yes, why not?

> Am I wrong?

Yes. It's obvious that the pulse response is a pure harmonic function because it is a resonance circuit without resistance.

Let the pulse be a voltage dirac pulse of value \$1 V\$ at \$t=0\$, and the output signal the voltage over the capacitor. Then it's clear that at \$t=0\$, \$U_C=1 V\$ and that the impulse response is a harmonic voltage starting at \$U_C = 1 V\$ with an angular frequency \$\omega_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{L C}}\$ (IIRC).

Then \$h(t)=cos(\omega_0 t)\$

Why bothering you with that?
Well, because \$\int_\infty^\infty cos(\omega_0 t) e^{-j \omega t}dt = \frac{1}{2}[\delta(\omega - \omega_0) + \delta(\omega + \omega_0)]\$.
I guess that integrating from *0* to \$\infty\$ gives only the \$\delta(\omega-\omega_0)\$ term.

Comment: The integral does not converge. \$e^{-j\omega t}=cos(\omega t)-j\sin(\omega t)\$ is not a converging function. Multiplying it against another non-convergent function doesn't change anything. This is why it's kinda weird to say that the integral exists and give it value.

Comment: I wasn't finished yet. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Does the frequency response of an ideal LC circuit exist?

It exists in theory but resistive losses in the circuit means that a practical circuit is impossible without using some kind of super-cooling. A low pass LC (without a resistor) has this response: -

[image]

[Picture source](http://www.stades.co.uk/RLC%20filters/RLC%20LPF.html).

And if you applied a sine wave of frequency Fc you will get an infinite output voltage at t = infinity. I say t = infinity because it will take that long for the output to become infinite due to the requirement for the LC to take in infinite energy from the signal source.

But, like I implied above, it's really quite beyond most people's budget to make one.

Answer (score 0):

The transfer function for an ideal LC lowpass is:

$$H(s)=\frac{1}{s^2LC+1}=\frac{\frac{1}{LC}}{s^2+\frac{1}{LC}}$$

which means that there is a pole (no zero) straighton the \$j\omega\$ axis, which means that the Laplace transform is of the form \$\text{u}(t)\sin\omega t\$, where \$\text{u}(t)\$ is the unit step => infinite oscillation. Here's a graphical confirmation:

[image: inf]

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of an LC circuit is whatever that behaviour happens to be.

We can try to describe the LC behaviour by modelling it with integrals over time, or defining a 'Frequency Response', which is a mathematical construct of our invention. When we want to let the integral be defined to infinite time, infinity is another mathematical construct of our invention.

If you want to ask whether mathematical constructs we have invented 'exist', then you are on the wrong site, mathematics, metamathematics (if it exists) or philosophy might be better.

If you want to ask whether they're useful to analyse LC circuits, and predict what they're going to do, and what their asymptotic behaviour is, then the answer is yes.

Comment: Yes - the usage of the term "exist" in this context is a bit "problematic". A transfer function cannot "exist" - it can be measured. However, this is possible only if the circuit under discussion (ideal L-C circuit) can be realized.